# an algebraic question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c$ are nonzero and distinct real numbers, I have to determine if

$$C=\frac {(a - c)^2}{c} + \frac{(a - b)^2}{a} + \frac{(b - c)^2}{b}$$

equals to zero. First, I can't apply any well-known inequality (for example CS), since we have real and not positive numbers. Second, I observe that if $a=b=c$, then $C=0$, a contradiction since $a,b,c$ are nonzero and distinct real numbers, but I can't find a more general method to prove it. Any help please?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are you asking if there are solutions?  It's obviously not always $0$ (just take $a,b,c$ all postive).

Comment: What happens if there are not all positive or all negative? How could you prove that $C$ in not equal to zero?

Comment: It's $0$ sometimes!  It's just not always $0$.

Comment: givw a counterexample for example

Comment: To see that there are some solutions, fix two variables and solve for the third.  Say we set $a=1,b=2$.  Then we solve $\frac {(1-c)^2}c+\frac {(1-2)^2}1+\frac {(2-c)^2}2=0$ which yields $c\approx -0.57474$.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the fractions by multiplying by $abc$ and have a cubic equation for the third.  This gives $ab(a-c)^2+bc(a-b)^2+ac(b-c)^2=Cabc.$  If you want to have $C=0$ and are given $a,b$, this is a cubic equation in $c$.  As all cubics have at least one real solution, there is at least one $c$ that gives $C=0$.  Now just pick a set of numbers that show $C$ can also be nonzero and your answer is that it is $0$ sometimes but not always.

Comment: I am trying to follow your answer, but it seems a little bit of confused to me

Comment: See if this is better

Comment: ok, it is better

Answer (score 0):

Take $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c=3$. Then $C=\frac{17}6$,

Comment: What happens if there are not all positive or all negative? How could you prove that $C$ in not equal to zero? $a,b,c$ are reals

Comment: Of course it *can* sometimes be equal to $0$. But your questin was whether that expression *is* $0$, and I proved that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can make $C=0$
by setting
$-a=b=c$.

Comment: $b,c$ are not distinct then

Comment: Oops. Oh well. Maybe this will help others.